# Finish getJSON request first before executing next line

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why is it that when I'm running this script step by step, using firebug, it set's the value of my form properly.
But when I just run it as is, it doesn't set the right value for the select.
What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery:**

```
function loadPlantillaDetails(btn) {
    ...    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/LoadPlantilla',
        data: {itemId: itemId},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {            
            $('#itemId').val(response.itemId);
            $('#item').val(response.item);
            $('#group').val(response.group);
            $('#region').val(response.region);
            loadProvince(); //just load the options for the province select based on the value of region
            $('#province').val(response.province);            
            loadMunicipality(); //just load the options for the municipality select based on the value of province
            var mun = (response.municipality+"").substr(2,3);            
            $('#municipality').val(mun);
            $('#itemDescription').val(response.itemDescription);
            $('#salaryGrade').val(response.salaryGrade);
            $('#code').val(response.code);
            $('#itemName').val(response.itemName);
            $('#pageNo').val(response.pageNo);
            $('#locked').val(response.locked);
            $('#vacant').val(response.vacant);

            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

**Sample return of `LoadPlantilla`:**

```
{
  "itemId" : 30,
  "item" : "579(3)",
  "group" : 3,
  "region" : 2,
  "province" : "07",
  "municipality" : "0705",
  "itemDescription" : "ELECTION OFFICER III",
  "salaryGrade" : "18",
  "code" : "EO3-245",
  "itemName" : "",
  "pageNo" : null,
  "locked" : 0,
  "vacant" : 1,
  "classification" : "P"
}
```

**Markup:**
Here is a code snippet of my modal where I'm having problems

```
<label for="region">Region</label>
<select name="region" id="region" onchange="loadProvince()">                            
    <c:forEach var="rgn" begin="0" end="17">
        <option value="${rgn}">${rgn}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<label for="province">Province</label>        
<select name="province" id="province" onchange="loadMunicipality()">                            
</select>                        

<label for="municipality">Municipality</label>
<select name="municipality" id="municipality">                            
</select>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I thought it's because the request was not finished yet so I moved the content of `success` to `done` method but apparently, the problem still persists.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/LoadPlantilla',
    data: {itemId: itemId},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#itemId').val(response.itemId);
    $('#item').val(response.item);
    $('#group').val(response.group);
    $('#region').val(response.region);
    loadProvince();
    $('#province').val(response.province);
    loadMunicipality();
    var mun = (response.municipality + "").substr(2, 3);        
    $('#municipality').val(mun);
    $('#itemDescription').val(response.itemDescription);
    $('#salaryGrade').val(response.salaryGrade);
    $('#code').val(response.code);
    $('#itemName').val(response.itemName);
    $('#pageNo').val(response.pageNo);
    $('#locked').val(response.locked);
    $('#vacant').val(response.vacant);

    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

Please help?

Here's my code for the `loadProvince()` and `loadMunicipality()`

```
function loadProvince() {
    var region = $("#region").val();
    $.getJSON("/chris/utilities/LoadProvince",
            {region: region
            },
    function(response) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'
                    + response[i].province + '">'
                    + response[i].area + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#province").html(options);
        loadMunicipality();
    }
    );
}

function loadMunicipality() {
    var province = $("#province").val();
    $.getJSON("/chris/utilities/LoadMunicipality",
            {province: province
            },
    function(response) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'
                    + response[i].municipality + '">'
                    + response[i].areaName + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#municipality").html(options);
    }
    );
}
```

Honestly, I don't really understand it much. I came up with these codes based on the ones I see from googling and here on stack overflow.

---

**EDIT 3:**

I know now why **it's failing to set the right option** when running normally but works fine when running with Firebug. It's **because my `loadRegion` and `loadMunicipality` is not done with the `getJSON` yet when the next line was executed.**

I believe **the solution would be to let the `loadRegion` and `loadMunicipality`** finish first before proceeding with the next line. How do I do this?
Thank you. :)

Comment: issue might be with the loadProvince(); loadMunicipality(); methods, since you load province based on value of region u might be calling another AJAX request and same with muncipality also.. if that is so try changing that, in sucess of loadProvince bind Muncipality in success of muncipality to other stuff.

Comment: @Gowtham.K.Reddy, I'm using `getJSON()`. I'm sorry, I'm just new to jQuery, can you elaborate? Thank you. :)

Comment: When and how is the `region` select populated?

Comment: @JonP, added it to my question. Please have a look. Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadPlantillaDetails(btn) {
//...
$.ajax({
    url: '/LoadPlantilla',
    data: { itemId: itemId },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#itemId').val(response.itemId);
        $('#item').val(response.item);
        $('#group').val(response.group);
        $('#region').val(response.region);
        //set all the required values first

        var mun = (response.municipality + "").substr(2, 3);
        //$('#municipality').val(mun);
        $('#itemDescription').val(response.itemDescription);
        $('#salaryGrade').val(response.salaryGrade);
        $('#code').val(response.code);
        $('#itemName').val(response.itemName);
        $('#pageNo').val(response.pageNo);
        $('#locked').val(response.locked);
        $('#vacant').val(response.vacant);

        // call load province loadProvince();
        loadProvince(response.province,mun);




    }
});
```

}

```
function loadProvince(selectedprovince,selectedMuncipality) {
var region = $("#region").val(); // u already set in the first ajax call
// here you are calling $.getJson() instead call ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: '/chris/utilities/LoadProvince', // this is ur url call to get province
    data: { region: region },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        // do stuff sucess province and call load muncipality method
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'
                    + response[i].province + '">'
                    + response[i].area + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#province").html(options);
        $('#province').val(selectedprovince);
        loadMunicipality(selectedMuncipality);
    },
    error: function () {
        // do error  stuff
    }
});
}

function loadMunicipality(selectedMuncipality) {
var province = $("#province").val(); // u already set in the first ajax call

// here also you are calling $.getJson() instead call ajax request

$.ajax({
    url: '/chris/utilities/LoadMunicipality', // this is ur url call to get Muncipality
    data: { province: province },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        // do stuff sucess Muncipality     

        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'
                    + response[i].municipality + '">'
                    + response[i].areaName + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#municipality").html(options);
        $('#municipality').val(selectedMuncipality);
        // show modal dialog or something in here....

        $('#modal').modal('show');
    },
    error: function () {
        // do error  stuff
    }
});
```

}

> I may or may not give exact solution for your problem. since it's not one line code or the other v ll come to know the prob unless you r having the actual environment running.
>   Please Note I am just guessing your code. Hope it helps you
>
> I have done changes to your code accordinly

Comment: Thank you. Okay, I'll explain my code a little bit. I have three select, `region`, `province`, and `municipality`. Based on the `region` selected, I will load all the `province` under that region, based on the province selected, I will load all `municipality` on that province. That's the purpose of the data I'm passing in my AJAX requests.

Comment: @J.Lucky but here u r filling all the three select in one function continuosly ri8. that's y its not coming. try changing the code accordingly it will work :) .

Comment: I have two different methods for filling the province and municipality. I added it now to my question.

Comment: @J.Lucky Done changes hava a look into it.

Comment: I need to load the province first, before setting it's value with `$('#province').val(response.province);` because it's empty at first. Anyways, I believe I know now the cause of this. Please refer to my edit 3. Thank you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61388/discussion-between-gowtham-k-reddy-and-j-lucky).

Comment: @Gowtham.K.Reddy please don't use "text speach" or "133t" e.g. u r ri8. Please use propper english and punctuation,capitals at the start of sentences are actually useful when it comes to readability.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for your valuble suggestion, As I am new to this I am not aware of it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply set the value of the select, you have to target the option that matches the value as a child and then set the selected attribute. Try something like this.

```
$('#region option[value="' + response.region + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Also, you'll need to fix the typo in your option HTML, it should be value, not valueu

```
<option valueu="${rgn}">${rgn}</option>
```

Should be

```
<option value="${rgn}">${rgn}</option>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gb7aq7bw/

Comment: _"You can't simply set the value of the select,"_ - Sure you can.

Comment: You "can", but that's not going to do what you're expecting to. Arbitrarily speaking, any html element, can have any attribute set, let's not get too literal here please

Comment: @BryanMoyles, I've tried this but still, it's not working. Thanks anyways. It's weird though because when I'm running firebug it's working.

Comment: It's actually .prop, not .attr, I tested it using JSFiddle and it seems like attr doesn't work anymore, it used to!

Comment: Setting the `value` property of a single-select select element will automatically select the option element with the specified value (assuming there is one with a matching value). This is expected and normal behaviour that works in all browsers.

Comment: P.S. You can see this for yourself in the following update to your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gb7aq7bw/1/ (Targeting the individual option is unnecessarily complicating it.)